# Which is the easiest way to draw mechanical diagrams in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, structural-analysis

I want to draw the following figure on my document.

[image]

I tried using `tikzpicture`.

[image]

The code snippet used to draw this figure is provided as an image. I am sorry for the inconvenience, my pc doesn't have internet access.

I was able to draw this much, but I don't know how to draw those supports.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Alan and welcome to TeX.SE! Normally we share code in text form, not as screenshots, so it is easier for others to help. Also removing the black borders of your images would help to improve the overview.

Comment: Take a look at the [stanli](https://ctan.org/pkg/stanli) package which is desined for structural engineering drawings.

Answer (score 1):

[`structmech`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/structmech) package can help

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{structmech}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\setstructmech{fill=gray}
\UDL{0,0}{5,0}
\HingeSupport{0,0}
\HingeSupport{5,0}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]